# At what speed would a wind affect a bullet?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, atmospheric-science, drag, speed, air

Firing a gun loaded with the fastest bullet (.220 Swift 1,422m/s or any bullet that is super fast and excellent aero dynamics) in a close range (2cm) from the tip of an air blower.  What would be the speed of the air coming out of the air blower to be able to deflect the bullet off course 90 degrees?

Comment: Depends upon time given for pushing the bullet

Answer (score 2):

For the bullet traveling directly at the air blower, to stop the bullet within $2cm$ needs, from the equations of motion a deceleration of $5\times10^{7}m/s^{2}$

Air resistance is $$F=\frac{1}{2}\rho ACv^2$$ see for example [this website](https://www.wired.com/2015/01/air-resistance-force-make-difference/)

For air $\rho = 1.2$, $C=0.2$ (estimate) and $A=\pi r^2$ with $r=2.8\times 10^{-3}m$

so from $F=ma$ with a mass of the bullet of $2g$

$$0.377r^2v^2 = 2\times 10^{-3}\times5\times10^{7}$$

$$v^2 = 3.4\times10^{10}$$

$$v = 184,000m/s$$

We could subtract the speed of the bullet from this, but it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, to stop the world fastest bullet with a wind  blower, the blower has to blow air at 184km/s?

Comment: @Hither Joe  Yes, if the calculations are correct

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the bullet does not know what the wind speed is.  The bullet only knows to travel in its given medium.  So if the wind was blowing from the side at the same 1,422m/s, then the bullet would travel sideways in that medium at the same rate that it is travelling forwards.  In this case, in one second it would travel forward 1,422 metres and sideways 1,422 metres, so it would travel at a 45 degree angle. This might be the answer you are looking for.  About 5,000 kph.

Otherwise, to travel in a complete 90 degree angle, it would have to have no forward travel at all, and complete sideways travel from the moment it leaves the gun.  So if you said that in the first millisecond after leaving the gun, it travelled directly sideways, then the wind speed would have to be 1,000 x 1,422 = 1,422,000 metres per second.  Darned fast.

But in general, any wind speed at all changes the path of a bullet.  This is a key aspect of being a target shooter, and is the reason why they set up ribbons along the rifle range, to show the wind speed at different points.

[image: rifle range]

Comment: I think you might clarify your first paragraph.  The bullet will leave the barrel in the same direction the barrel is pointed.  Then the bullet will curve in the direction of the wind as it travels.  So in other words, the bullet won't be going in a straight line.  I think you are saying that it moves at a 45 degree angle **in the moving reference frame of the wind**, but that's only true at the instant it leaves the barrel.

Comment: @James  I had made the assumption of a constant speed for the bullet.  It would travel in a straight line at a 45 degree angle.  it would travel one foot to the side for each foot forward, or 45 degrees.   It would not form a curve until the bullet started to slow down, which of course does happen immediately.

Comment: For that to be true, the bullet would have to instantaneously change from 0 m/s side motion to 1422 m/s side motion, which would be an infinite acceleration.  Instead, the bullet is pushed by the wind, and the bullet will be accelerated sideways.  The side velocity of the bullet will depend on things such as the bullet cross-section, the wind speed, and the amount of time it's been pushed.

Comment: I'm trying to take this seriously. You would have to have a very very fast moving air blower, or a very very (world record) long one blowing incredibly fast and its anybody's guess how long it would take to deflected even an average bullet (in a circular arc).

Comment: @James  That would be no faster than the acceleration of the bullet from nothing to 1,422m/s in the original direction.  Remember that the bullet does not know that it is moving sideways.  It is simply the medium in which is flies that is moving.  Imagine that you are walking perpendicular to a moving walkway.  The instant you step onto the walkway, you are moving sideways as well as length ways.  Was your acceleration instant?  Except for the inertia, you would not know that your motion has changed.

Comment: Well, you make two claims here that are totally false.  1) The bullet accelerated from 0 to 1422 m/s while it traveled the length of the gun barrel.  That's not infinite acceleration.  2) When stepping on a moving walkway my side motion is not instantaneously equal to the walkway speed.  If I were standing straight up I would fall over sideways.  To avoid falling I have to lean over as I step on.  My body is compressed lengthwise as the force on my feet accelerates my entire body.

Comment: @RobTristram  Yes it would need to be a VERY big blower.  Think about crossing a river in a canoe.  You start in the calm section on the edge of the river paddling west at 5kph  Then you hit the moving water that is moving south at 5kph.  You would instantly be moving south-west at a 45 degree angle.  There would be no slippage where you continue to mover just west.  The instant you cross into the moving water, you will be moving south-west.  The same is true of the bullet.

Comment: Saying that an object will instantly move at the velocity of the medium it is in is just not true.  If it were true, then the bullet shot from gun on a day with no wind would just instantly stop... and float I guess.

Comment: @James as with most physics, I am thinking of an idealized situation.  So think of a piece of paper crossing onto the moving walkway (or the moving river in my second example).  Yes, there will be some inertia, but very little.

Comment: @James  I'll give you one more example.  You are probably aware that if you shoot a bullet horizontally and drop a bullet, they hit the ground at the same instant because of the curvature of spacetime because of gravity.  The same is true of a horizontal laser beam.  It will hit the ground at the same instant as the two bullets (on a really large, flat planet.)  The reason is because the medium in which they are travelling is all curving in the same direction.  This is what I'm thinking of.

Comment: Ok, but you are assuming that the bullet has such a small inertia that it is immediately going the same speed sideways as the wind.  To be consistent, you need to also assume that the bullet immediately stops moving downrange (because there is no wind in that direction).  I think that this observation should demonstrate that the bullet inertia is NOT negligible when acted on by the air.

Comment: I agree with @James that the bullet is not travelling with the speed of the medium. As it leaves the muzzle it will become accelerated by the wind in the transverse direction, but it may never reach the wind speed before hitting the ground.